# MySql if statement in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a code that is not working

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS fnameLname, s.student_number, u.user_id
FROM user u
LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE 
case when @filter != ''
then ((u.firstname REGEXP CONCAT('^[', @filter, ']') OR u.lastname REGEXP CONCAT('^[', @filter, ']')) OR student_number REGEXP CONCAT('^[', @filter, ']'))
else 1=1 
AND (u.user_type_id = 0)
ORDER BY u.lastname, u.firstname
```

I want to select users from table *user*, I have implement search field (for searching on student_number or on start of firstname and lastname (just first letter of firstname or lastname)).

For example, if I search for "j s", it would match for example John Smith, and not John Moses. It would also match Jeremy Sassone. @filter is control parameter in asp.net.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Clarify that you search for initials, or prefixes

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to use a CASE statement. Looks like you could just OR several WHERE clauses together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `and` and `or` for this. No need for the complicated `case when`s, and inner `case when`s, etc.:

```
where ( ( @filter != '%'
          and ( u.firstname REGEXP CONCAT('^[', @filter, ']')
                or u.lastname REGEXP CONCAT('^[', @filter, ']')
                or student_number REGEXP CONCAT('^[', @filter, ']')
             )
       )
       or @filter = '%'
      )
and   u.user_type_id = 0
```

The default value for @filter would be '%' - with an empty string it's a syntax error because of the empty square brackets.

Comment: I don't know but if I replace @filter with any string (empty or non empty), it does not work. It also does not work in asp.net.

Comment: Are you using a double equals sign as in the example, or a single equals? When it doesn't work does it error or just fail to bring anything back?

Comment: I copied the code from above. In HeidiSQL it gives an error, in asp.net when I want to fill gridview it doesn't bring anything back.

Comment: It should be a single = sign when checking for blank. I also assume that you are just replacing the WHERE clause of your current query with this, rather than treating this as the whole query.

Comment: Indeed. It was a typo.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem. If I replace @filter with empty string ('') in HeidiSQL, I get error: SQL Error (1139): Got error 'brackets ([ ]) not balanced' from regexp. If replaced with non empty string, then it works. But what I want is to have one query for both cases (for empty and non empty string).

Comment: It appears that MySQL treats empty square brackets as a syntax error so never tries to execute the SQL (if it did then it should bypass the regexp). All I can think of to suggest is that if filter is empty then pass it as a single space, and in the SQL check for filter having a value of a single space.

Comment: @Kickstart now it works. Empty string ('') was replaced by '%' and now it works like a charm :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman it's solved now. I'll edit your answer and accept it.